# How I can to avoid IoC locator in next case?

Tags: c#, wcf, dependency-injection, ninject, service-locator

In brief: I want resolve interface by prop in entity.
I have self hosted wcf and use ninject for DI.
My working code for example:

```
//program.cs
...
private static StandardKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();

    kernel.Bind<IDbConnectionFactory>().ToMethod(c =>
        new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(
            conString, 
            SqlServerDialect.Provider))
        .InSingletonScope();
        
    kernel.Bind<IControllerProccessor>().To<ControllerProccessor>()
        .WhenInjectedInto<HelloWorldService>().WithConstructorArgument(kernel);
        
    kernel.Bind<IControllerProccessor>().To<Vendor1Proccessor>()
        .Named("vendor1"); 
        
    kernel.Bind<IControllerProccessor>().To<Vendor2Proccessor>()
        .Named("vendor2"); 

    return kernel;
}
...

//IControllerProccessor.cs
public interface IControllerProccessor
{
    SimpleController Ctr { get; set; }
    bool sendMsg(string msg);
}

//Vendor1Proccessor.cs
public class Vendor1Proccessor : IControllerProccessor
{
    public SimpleController Ctr {get; set;}

    public bool sendMsg(string msg)
    {
        //specific to vendor code, for example calls to vendor1 SDK
        Console.WriteLine("Controller id: {0} vendor:{1} recivied msg: {2}",
            Ctr.Id,
            "Vendor1Class",
            msg);
        return true;
    }
}

//Vendor2Proccessor.cs
public class Vendor2Proccessor : IControllerProccessor
{
    public SimpleController Ctr { get; set; }

    public bool sendMsg(string msg)
    {
        //specific to vendor code, for example calls to vendor1 SDK
        Console.WriteLine("Controller id: {0} vendor:{1} recivied msg: {2}",
            Ctr.Id,
            "Vendor2Class",
            msg);
        return true;
    }
}

//ControllerProccessor.cs
public class ControllerProccessor : IControllerProccessor
{
    public SimpleController Ctr {get; set;}

    private readonly IKernel kernel;

    public ControllerProccessor(IKernel _kernel)
    {
        kernel = _kernel;
    }

    public bool sendMsg(string msg)
    {
        var param = new Ninject.Parameters.PropertyValue("Ctr", Ctr);
        return kernel.Get<IControllerProccessor>(Ctr.Vendor, param).sendMsg(msg);
    }
}

//HelloWorldService.cs
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory;
    private readonly IControllerProccessor ctrProccessor;

    public HelloWorldService(IDbConnectionFactory _dbFactory, IControllerProccessor _ctrProccesor)
    {
        dbFactory = _dbFactory;
        ctrProccessor = _ctrProccesor;
    }

    public bool sendMsgToAllControllers(string msg)
    {
        var db = dbFactory.Open();
        var controllers = db.Select<SimpleController>();

        foreach(var ctr in controllers)
        {
            ctrProccessor.Ctr = ctr;
            ctrProccessor.sendMsg(msg);
        }
        db.Close();

        return true;
    }

}

//SimpleController.cs
[DataContract]
[Alias("SimpleController")]
public class SimpleController
{
    [AutoIncrement]
    [DataMember]
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Vendor { get; set; }
}
```

When I call sendMsgToAllControllers("TEST_MESSAGE") console output:

```
Controller id: 2 vendor:Vendor1Class recivied msg: TEST MESSAGE
Controller id: 3 vendor:Vendor2Class recivied msg: TEST MESSAGE
Controller id: 4 vendor:Vendor2Class recivied msg: TEST MESSAGE
```

How I can refactor above implementation so that it was in DI style, and dont use IoC locator anti-pattern (or in my case this is not anti-pattern) ?

In future I will move implementations (vendor1, vendor2, etc..) in separate assembly and do runtime binding. (Here I want to plugin system)

I also would appreciate any suggestions to improve my code. Very thanks.

## Modification of implementation

After thinking process I came to the following:
I remove ControllerProccessor class instead I create ControllerProcessorFactory:

```
public class ControllerProcessorFactory : IControllerProcessorFactory
{        
    private readonly IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot;

    public ControllerProcessorFactory(IResolutionRoot _resolutionRoot)
    {
        resolutionRoot = _resolutionRoot;
    }

    public IControllerProcessor Create(SimpleController ctr)
    {
        IControllerProcessor processor = resolutionRoot.Get<IControllerProcessor>(ctr.Vendor);
        processor.Ctr = ctr;
        return processor;
    }
}
```

In Bindings:

```
kernel.Bind<IControllerProcessorFactory>().To<ControllerProcessorFactory>();
kernel.Bind<IControllerProcessor>().To<Vendor1Processor>()
    .Named("vendor1");
kernel.Bind<IControllerProcessor>().To<Vendor2Processor>()
    .Named("vendor2");
```

Usage (wcf class):

```
public class HelloWorldService : IHelloWorldService
{
    private readonly IDbConnectionFactory dbFactory;
    private readonly IControllerProcessorFactory ctrProcessorFactory;

    public HelloWorldService(IDbConnectionFactory _dbFactory, IControllerProcessorFactory _ctrProcFactory)
    {
        dbFactory = _dbFactory;
        ctrProcessorFactory = _ctrProcFactory;
    }

    public bool sendMsgToAllControllers(string msg)
    {
        var db = dbFactory.Open();
        var controllers = db.Select<SimpleController>();

        foreach(var ctr in controllers)
        {
            var ctrProcessor = ctrProcessorFactory.Create(ctr);
            ctrProcessor.sendMsg(msg);
        }
        db.Close();

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Whether or not the dependency on the container is [an anti-pattern](blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern) or not depends on the [role it plays in your application](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/08/25/ServiceLocatorrolesvs.mechanics/). In short: if the code that depends on the container is part of the [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/), it is okay; otherwise it's a problem.

Comment: @Steven Thx, I read these articles, so I'm here.  How I can  to refactor my existed code?

Comment: Your `ControllerProccessor` doesn't seem to have any business logic, so you can easily move that `ControllerProccessor` into your Composition Root; that  will solve the problem.

Comment: @Steven Thank you for trying to help. Is program.cs not composition root? I define ControllerProccesor in bindings and futher I use it only on constructors. And the fact that I use in the ControllerProccessor `return kernel.Get<IControllerProccessor>(Ctr.Vendor, param).sendMsg(msg);` is not considered as service locator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`kernel.Get<IControllerProccessor>(Ctr.Vendor, param)` is service locator, 
but then again that doesn't always mean "it" is a problem. If it's easily interchangable, then it's not a big deal (well at least that's the opinion of some). Easily interchangeable? Create a specific factory interface whose only responsibility is to return all the processors.
The implementation then would consist of exactly `return kernel.Get<IControllerProccessor>(Ctr.Vendor, param);`. As long as the implementation is part of the composition root this specfici dependency on ninject is ok.

### Shorter Alternative

Now, to be honest, your design looks superfluosly complicated to me, but then again, i don't know all the details. So for now i'm just using the name parameter, but you can easily add parameters (almost) as you like, it'll still work:

Just inject a `Func<string, IControllerProcessor>` instead of the kernel:

```
public ControllerProccessor(
     Func<string,IControllerProcessor>> controllerProcessorFactory)
```

You can then specfiy a binding as follows:

```
private static IControllerProcessor CreateSpecificControllerProcessor(
    IResolutionRoot resolutionRoot, string vendorName)
{
    return resolutionRoot.Get<IControllerProcessor>(vendorName);
}

Bind<Func<IControllerProcessor>()
    .ToConstant(vendorName => CreateSpecficiControllerProcessor(this.Kernel, vendorName));
```

Instead of specifying the Binding for the `Func` it *might* be possible to use [Ninject.Extensions.Factory](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Factory). Note however, that when you use this extension it won't be possible to `Bind` any `Func` manually anymore (the binding will be overriden by the extensions generation mechanism).

Comment: Thx, this is very similar to what I need. But when I put `kernel.Bind<Func<IEnumerable<IControllerProcessor>>>().ToConstant(vendorName => CreateSpecificControllerProcessor(kernel, vendorName));` I get Error: `The type arguments for method 'Ninject.Syntax.IBindingToSyntax<System.Func<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<wcfService.IControllerProcessor>>>.ToConstant<TImplementation>(TImplementation)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.`

Comment: Also after thinking, I replace ControllerProcessor on IControllerProcessorFactory, see my post upd.

Comment: @Vilix yes sorry, made a mistake there It shouldn't have had the `IEnumerable` in the code (I was confused because I was looking at ewassefs answer). The solution you chose is exactly what i wanted to propse. The `Func` alternative is principially the same. As the factory interface is more explicit I'd stick with the factory interface as you have chosen. Hint: it's best practice to use ctor-injection instead of doing `processor.Ctr = ctr`.

Comment: @Vilix this can be done by adding a `TypeMatchingConstructorArgument` to the `resolutionRoot.Get` call.

Answer (score 0):

Look at Dynamic module loading in their documentation. 
i.e.

```
    kernel.Load("*.dll");
```

But make sure you do this at startup so you don't overwhelm your system at runtime. 
As far as your pattern, I would recommend using the GetAll() method on the kernel as that will give you more flexibility and control

```
    IEnumerable<IControllerProccessor> processors = kernel.GetAll<IControllerProccessor>();
    foreach(var processor in processors)
        processor.sendMsg(....);
```

Comment: but how kernel.GetAll<IControllerProccessor>() put SimpleController entities to Ctr prop ? In proccesors I need work with SimpleController data's from DB.